# Register class passing it to App class from android project

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I write printing service which will be used in `Android`. I need to `register` `class PrintService` which is placed directly in `Android project` therefore pass it throuh `App()` of `XamarinForms library`. I already created `AndroidInitializer class` but i do not know how could i pass it here:

`LoadApplication(new App());` the way in `XamarinForms` library's `App` `container`'s variable it would be registered correctly:

Hope you got my point. Please of your answers.

**Android project > MainActivity.cs**

```
[Activity(Label = "XamarinForms", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        LoadApplication(new App());
    }
    public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
    {
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }

    public class AndroidInitializer
    {
        public void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer containerRegistry)
        {
            containerRegistry.RegisterType<IPrintService, PrintService>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
        }
    }
}
```

**XamarinForms library:** (here i want to pass registrastion from AndroidInitializer)

```
public partial class App : Application
{
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


var container = new UnityContainer()
                .AddExtension(new Diagnostic())
                .RegisterInstance(mapper)
                .RegisterType<IDatabase, Db>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager())
                .RegisterType<ILogger, Logger>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
}
```

**UPDATE:**
So far i did this way but i am not sure whether is correct approach. As you see below i pass in constructor of `App` from `MainActivity` the type as `new UnityContainer`. Then in `App` class already i do the trick `looping through all registered` (there will be 2 : unity Container itself (certainly i don't need it) and `PrintService`) so i add it. What do you think is it correct?

in **Android project > MainActivity.cs**:

```
LoadApplication(new App(new UnityContainer().RegisterType<IPrintService, PrintService>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager())));
```

and in **XamarinForms library:** :

```
public partial class App : Application
    {
            public App()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
    
    
    var container = new UnityContainer()
                    .AddExtension(new Diagnostic())
                    .RegisterInstance(mapper)
                    .RegisterType<IDatabase, Db>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager())
                    .RegisterType<ILogger, Logger>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());

//added PrintService from ctor:
foreach (var registration in unityContainer.Registrations)
{
        if (registration.RegisteredType == typeof(IUnityContainer))
              continue;
        container.RegisterType(
                    registration.RegisteredType,
                    registration.MappedToType,
                    registration.Name);
            }
}
```

Comment: Can you try to use [DependencyService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction) to do in your project?

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT not really understand how i could use that in my situation? Could you show as an answer? P.S What you think about my UPDATE's propostion?

Answer (score 1):

While I haven't used UnityContainer, the general question here is how to combine platform-specific initialization with platform-independent initialization.

Any "clean" design will ensure platform-independent code (X-Forms) doesn't need any awareness of platform specifics.

One approach would be to pass a "callback" to App constructor:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App(Action<UnityContainer> registerPrint)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var uc = new UnityContainer() ...;
        
        registerPrint(uc);
    }
}
```

Android / MainActivity.cs:

```
.. OnCreate ...
{
    ...
    // Pass a reference to a function, so App ctor can call it.
    LoadApplication(new App(RegisterPrintService));
}

// This is called later, in App constructor, via an Action.
private void RegisterPrintService(UnityContainer uc)
{
    ... create PrintService, and register it ...
}
```

similar on each other platform ...

**UPDATE**

The fundamental problem here is that UnityContainer should be created first, then the PrintService should be created and registered with Unitycontainer.

To do this, we have Android code pass a function to X-Forms App code. This allows App to create container, then “call back” into Android code, by calling that function as an action. The Unitycontainer is a parameter to that function, so Android code can work with it.

——————————-

This can also be done via [a dependency service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction). (Link from Cherry Bu's comment.).

This would be the interface declaration, in X-Forms project:

```
public interface IRegisterPrintService
{
    void Register(UnityContainer uc);
}
```

In Android, declare class:

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(YourApp.Droid.RegisterPrintService))]
namespace YourApp.Droid
{
  public class RegisterPrintService : IRegisterPrintService
  {
    public void Register(UnityContainer uc)
    {
        ... create PrintService, and register it ...
    }
  }
}
```

There would no longer be a parameter passed to App constructor:

```
LoadApplication(new App());
```

In X-Forms:

```
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var uc = new UnityContainer() ...;
        
        IRegisterPrintService rps = DependencyService.Get<IRegisterPrintService>();
        rps.Register(uc);
    }
```

Comment: isn;t similar to what i did in UPDATE ?

Comment: @Arie - yes, except what you did in a loop in X-Forms class App, I moved to AndroidPlatformRegistration, which is in Android / MainActivity. Whether it is better to do it your way or this way, depends on whether "added PrintService from ctor" is more easily done once in cross-platform code [your solution], or would be more straightforward if done in each platform's platform-specific code [this answer]. I don't know enough from your sample code to know which makes more sense in your case. Go ahead and use your judgement; just wanted you to be aware of this alternative.

Comment: @Arie, for instance, **maybe** if done on each platform, instead of *looping* over existing Registrations, you might have a variable that refers to the PrintService, and be able to do the logic on it directly. Again, whether that is preferable is up to you. Where do you call or access AndroidInitializer in your approach? (In this answer, add needed code to AndroidPlatformRegistration.)

Comment: I think you missed my UPDATE in main post, see now i am passing now it to ctor directly. Look again. That works.

Comment: @Arie. Your update makes no sense to me. Does it even compile? Check what you wrote. 1) You call new UnityContainer in two different places. Is this valid? At best, its poor practice. 2) You pass a parameter to App constructor, but your app constructor doesn’t take a parameter. 3) You have to find the printservice again, by looping. That’s a bit hacky. I have no loop. I only create one UnityContainer. What I pass is totally different than what you pass. I pass a function.

Comment: @Aria. Ah ha. You misread my code. That is not a call to AndroidPlatformRegistration where I do new App. There are no parentheses after function name. I pass in a reference to that function. The function is called later, inside App constructor, as an action. Look at the type of parameter where App constructor is defined. Read about actions.